# Remove from a list of strings, those strings that have only empty spaces or that are made up of less than 3 alphanumeric characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, list, regex-group

```py
import re

sentences_list = ['Hay 5 objetos rojos sobre la mesada de ahí.', 'Debajo de la mesada hay 4 objetos', '', '     ', "\taa!", '\t\n \n', '\n ', 'ai\n ', 'Salto rapidamente!!!', 'y la vio volar', '!', '   aa', 'aa', 'día']

#The problem with this is that there are several cases that need to be eliminated 
# and the complexity to figure that out should be resolved with a regex.
sentences_list = [i for a,i in enumerate(sentences_list) if i != ' ']

print(repr(sentences_list)) #print the already filtered list to verify
```

I got these strings with a sentence separator, the problem is that some sentences aren't really sentences or aren't really linguistically significant units.

- Those strings that have less than 3 alphanumeric characters (that is, 2 characters or less) must be eliminated from the list.
- Those strings that are empty `""` or `"      "` , or that are made up of single symbols `"...!"`, `";"`, `".\n"`, `"\taa!"` must be eliminated from the list.
- Those strings that have only escape characters and nothing else, except symbols or that have less than 3 alphanumeric characters, for example `"\t\n ab ."` , `"\n ."`, `"\n"` must be eliminated from the list.

This is how the correct list should look after having filtered those elements that are substrings that do not meet the conditions

```
['Hay 5 objetos rojos sobre la mesada de ahí.', 'Debajo de la mesada hay 4 objetos', 'Salto rapidamente!!!', 'y la vio volar', 'día']
```

Comment: What is your question? You seem to have identified the conditions which need to be satisfied to include an element in your filtered list. Did you try implementing these conditions? What, _specifically_ are you having trouble with? Please review [ask] and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). It would help us help you if you also provided a [mre] of your attempt, and described how it fails to meet expectations.

Comment: It is a problem with defining the regex that allows the decision to be made about which elements to remove from the list and which not.

Comment: Could you clarify why you call `enumerate` and then don't use `a`?

Comment: @trincot The solution that Unmitigated published works quite well, since apparently it is no longer considering symbols like !, , . or ..., as alphanumeric characters so they don't add up. And respect to the escape characters, these are not detected, so they do not interfere in the decision to eliminate the substrings either.

Comment: @trincot I try doing the deletions using enumate, though that only works for too specific types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count the number of alphanumeric characters in a string by calling [`.isalnum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum) on each character and summing these values. Then you can keep only the strings that have at least 3 of these with a list comprehension.

```py
sentences_list = [s for s in sentences_list if sum(c.isalnum() for c in s) >= 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this `if` clause:

```
if len(re.sub(r"\W", "", i)) >= 3
```